# Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) memory parameter invalid or not specified when setting memory_max_target parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle18c

I am using Oracle db 18c XE 64 bit. I am trying to enable Automatic Memory Management. In order to do so, I have to set memory_max_target parameter first then restart the database then set memory_target parameter according to the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-0E201F66-D280-472A-AD80-20AB8F7E9C01. I started cmd then opened sqlplus using `sqlplus / as sysdba` command then issued `alter system set memory_max_target=2000M`. The system altered successfully. The next step was to set memory_target. I shudown the db using `SHUTDOWN` command. then exited sqlplus to reopen it using `sqlplus /nolog` then `connect / as sysdba` to see error "

```
ORA-56752: Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) memory parameter invalid or not
specified
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
```

"
Why am I seeing this error?

Comment: check out your alert.log file to see if you have any other error. It will also show you what it is using as parameters. Plus, the error is shown when you try to startup the db, or just when you connect?

Comment: Where can I find the alert.log? The error is displayed when using startup. I figured out now that the value 2000M is actually invalid because before changing memory_max_target, the values of sga_target was 1536M and pga_aggregate_target was 512 and the pga allocated since the instance startup was about 272M. So the minimum memory_target should be 1536+512=2048M. And memory_max_target can not be lower than memory_target, so 2000M is an invalid value. But the strange thing is that 2048m should be a valid value. But I tried it and tried 2052M too and it displays the same error on startup.

Comment: The more strange thing is that setting memory_max_target to 1000M does not display the error. But when checking it's value after startup it shows 2052M not 1000M!

Comment: according to the doc, XE won't allow more than 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Is there a reference for that? Anyway, 2048M is actually 2GB. And it set memory_max_target to 2052M which is more than 2GB.

Comment: [here's the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/oracle-database-xe-ram-limitation.html)

Comment: The doc says it can only use 2GB but it does not say you can not set it to more than 2GB.

Comment: The complete error is the following:
Error code: ORA-56752
Description: Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) memory parameter invalid or not specified
Cause: An invalid parameter or a value more than the maximum memory allowed was specified
Action: Use the allowed parameter or reduce the memory size, upgrade to the Standard or Enterprise edition.

It clearly says 'reduce'. I don't have an XE install, so cannot check the behavior in different cases.